# rows group by name and get null values

Tags: sql-server, null, group-by, view

I have following structure in my View

```
**Month|    Doctor| Executive|  Revenue**
1      |      A   |   1      |  100
1      |      B   |   1      |  200
NULL   |      C   |   1      |  0
NULL   |      D   |   2      |  0
2      |      A   |   1      |  400
1      |      E   |   1      |  100
NULL   |      F   |   2      |  0
2      |      A   |   1      |  300
```

I want the result as

```
**Executive|    Doctor| Revenue|    Month**
  1        |      A   | 100    |    1
  1        |      B   | 200    |    1
  1        |      C   | 0      |    1
  1        |      E   | 100    |    1
```

I want all the doctors of Executive 1 to come in the output even the column Month has NULL value for it.

when I tried with the query

```
select DocName,sum(rate),sum(patients) from DoctorRevenue
where SECode=1 and VisitMonth=10
group by DocName
```

it is giving A,B,E only but I want C to come in the output.

Comment: try isnull(VisitMonth,10)=10

Comment: Your table structure and query do not suite to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include NULL in the WHERE clause for the column [VisitMonth], i.e.

`WHERE SECode = 1 AND (VisitMonth = 1 OR VisitMonth IS NULL)`

Brackets are required.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2541f)

Answer (score 0):

You need add `VisitMonth IS NULL` in where also use `ISNULL` function to show `1` as month for `NULL` values. Try this.

```
select Isnull(VisitMonth,1),DocName,sum(rate),sum(patients) from DoctorRevenue
where  SECode=1 
and    (VisitMonth = 1 OR VisitMonth IS NULL)
group by DocName,Isnull(VisitMonth,1)
```

Comment: some records are missing from the output. If some doctor X is associated with Executive 1 but Month column is 2, output should show the record (X,NULL,0) also .. basically the output should show all the doctors associated with Executive 1 and their months.. From your above query if doctor X is not from 10th month and for Doctor X no NULL exists.. it should give (X,NULL,0) in output